# Cannot find a way to return an Array of objects in Angular 8 component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm newbie with Angular 8. I'm creating a method within a service that allows me to return a dynamically constructed data structure.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfig } from 'src/app/app.config';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BibliographyParserService {

  private editionUrls = AppConfig.evtSettings.files.editionUrls || [];
  private bibliographicCitations: Array<BibliographicCitation> = [];

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
  }

  public getBibliographicCitations() {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    this.editionUrls.forEach((path) => {
      this.http.get(path, { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(map((response: string) => {
        Array.from(parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/xml').getElementsByTagName('bibl')).forEach(citation => {
          if (citation.getElementsByTagName('author').length === 0 &&
              citation.getElementsByTagName('title').length === 0 &&
              citation.getElementsByTagName('date').length === 0) {
            const interfacedCitation: BibliographicCitation = {
              title: citation.textContent.replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
            };
            if (!this.bibliographicCitations.includes(interfacedCitation)) { this.bibliographicCitations.push(interfacedCitation); }
          } else {
            const interfacedCitation: BibliographicCitation = {
              author: citation.getElementsByTagName('author'),
              title: String(citation.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]).replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
              date: citation.getElementsByTagName('date')[0],
            };
            if (!this.bibliographicCitations.includes(interfacedCitation)) { this.bibliographicCitations.push(interfacedCitation); }
          }
        });
        this.bibliographicCitations.forEach(biblCit => {
          console.log(((biblCit.author === undefined) ? '' : biblCit.author),
                      ((biblCit.title === undefined) ? '' : biblCit.title),
                      ((biblCit.date === undefined) ? '' : biblCit.date));
        });
      }),
      );
    });
    // THIS IS RETURNED EMPTY IN THE COMPONENT WHEN ACTUALLY IT IS FULL!
    return this.bibliographicCitations;
  }
}

export interface BibliographicCitation {
  author?: HTMLCollectionOf<Element>;
  title: string;
  date?: Element;
}
```

In the documentation I consulted I noticed that there is no such "complex" example, in the sense that the data I want to take is inside an `http` call, which in turn is inside a loop! And I obviously want to return them when the cycle is completed.
If I call the method outside with `console.log(this.bps.getBibliographicCitations())`, it now returns an empty data structure:

```
[]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I would like to know if there was a way to return the data by avoiding to immediately `subscribe` into the service.

Comment: You `http.get` is async. You should be returning and subscribing to the observable returned form this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Liam-ReinstateMonica I agree. But, in my example, I am in a cycle. If I had been out I would have done `return this.http.get(path, { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(map((response: string) => { [...]` and then `subscribe` in the component. What I hope for, it was that Angular would still allow data to be returned after a cycle of `http` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we have to do here is return an observable stream of http calls by using normal javascript `map` function.

```
public getBibliographicCitations() {
  return this.editionUrls.map((path) =>  this.http.get(path, { responseType: 'text' 
  }));
}
```

Then to get the values we have to subscribe it as observables are always [lazy](https://medium.com/@mpodlasin/promises-vs-observables-4c123c51fe13). To subscribe we can do the following:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

forkJoin(this.getBibliographicCitations()).subscribe(console.log);
```

Here I am using [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) which will wait for all your api calls. And once everything succeeds you would be able to see the data in console.

Whatever you need to map or act on values which you get from response you should do that inside subscribe function as below

```
forkJoin(this.getBibliographicCitations()).subscribe((responses) => {
  // Update instance variables accordingly
  this.bibliographicCitations = //;
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but what I meant there is to map urls to http observables. forEach doesn't return anything. I have not asked to change pipe(map()). Can you please read the  answer one more time

Comment: No, my bad, I think your right, I misunderstood the OPs code. I've add the setting of `this.bibliographicCitations` if only so I can alter my vote. But this seems about right

Comment: Doing `forkJoin(this.getHttpCallsOBSStream()).subscribe((responses) => {` and in the next line `responses.forEach(response => {` and returning the updated data structure out of these blocks, it seems to work perfectly! `forkJoin` was just what I was looking for, great!
PS: `this.getHttpCallsOBSStream()` return `this.editionUrls.map((path) =>  this.http.get(path, { responseType: 'text' }))`

Comment: Glad it helped you.